# How can I remove junk characters with regex?

Tags: regex

I have a web application that reads the contents of a web page and parses the sentences using an NLP algorithm. I have been using regex to split the contents into single sentences and then parsing them.

I would like to remove characters like `Â` from my sentences. These characters, I imagine, are because of the HTML encoding.

I obviously cannot use a regex like `[^\w\d]+` or its variations because I need the punctuations intact. Of course I could add individual exceptions for each of the punctuation like `[^\w\d\.,:]+` and so on, but I would like it if there is an easier way to do this, like probably a character class that knows it is a... funny character?

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: The app is built with PHP and I am using a simple `file_get_contents()` to fetch the HTML data from the site and reading the contents inside `<p>` tags.

Comment: Is it a perl script, You process the page?

Comment: Which regex? A language is helpful.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to figure out the encoding of the page and handle that correctly?

Comment: @TimPietzcker but your way doesn't use regex! this is too simple!

Comment: Sorry I didn't provide more details. Yes, my app is in PHP, and I process the page through a simple `file_get_contents` call, and reading inside the <p> tags in the file.

Comment: You could always loop through the content and remove anything with an ASCII code above 127. Inefficient and brute force.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was mentioned in the comments by @TheGreatCO but you are able to create a character class of "special" characters. You can use the hex code values to create a range in a character class. So for any special character over ASCII 127 would be this.

```
[\x80-\xFE]
```

That would match anything but your most basic characters. For reference sake, [here's a list of the ASCII character table with their hex codes](http://www.asciitable.com/).

[This page discusses the different ways you can reference special characters in regex.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/nonprint.html)

Answer (score 1):

I found this regexpr helpful to identify junk character in a file using atom

[^(\x20-\x7F\p{Sc})]